# How can I convert HTTP GET request to just a number?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python requests to get a value for a virtual stock price. Here is my code.

```
ramt = requests.get('https://www.spookvooper.com/Exchange/Available', params={'id': ticker}) 
ramtc = ramt.content
print(ramtc)
```

This outputs b'0', but I need it to just be 0. How would I  be able to convert this to a usable number?

Comment: convert to integer ``int(b'0')``

Comment: It still printed b'0'

Answer (score 0):

you can simply get the `json` content like this:

```
ramt = requests.get('https://www.spookvooper.com/Exchange/Available', params={'id': ticker}) 
ramtc = ramt.json()
print(ramtc)
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`ramt.content` returns the response in bytes.

You are looking for `ramt.text`. This will return the response in unicode. There is no need to convert.